# Header and Footer repeating for each element in ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am trying to have a listView in one of my Fragments . I tried addHeaderView and addFooterView but that scrolled the header and footer along with list so I tried a different approach but the header and footer is being repeated for each element

My Fragment Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.solutionnest.fragment.RemoteListFragment">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Device List"
        android:id="@+id/listHeader"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="#f4438fd3"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/listContainer"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/deviceName" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/listElementSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ListBoxSize" android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:text="Add"
            android:onClick="addDevice"
            android:id="@+id/addDevice"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f4438fd3"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:onClick="deleteDevice"
            android:id="@+id/deleteDevice"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f4438fd3"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My getView method in adapter looks like

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Device device = (Device)getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_remote_list,parent ,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } holder.name.setText(device.getDeviceName());


        return convertView;

    }
```

Comment: What is your objective? If you want a header and footer for the whole list, that do not scroll with the list, put the header, `ListView`, and footer into a vertical `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi after a bit struggle got this fixed .Posting what worked for me..It seems that The list content must be a part of seperate layout file to achieve above requirement my new layout and view configuration are `

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Device device = (Device)getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_remote_list_content,parent ,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(deviceList.isEmpty())
        {
            holder.name.setText("No Devices");
        }
        else {
            holder.name.setText(device.getDeviceName());
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        }

        return convertView;

    }
```

`The fragment_remote_list.xml layout was divided into 2 files

fragment_remote_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.solutionnest.fragment.RemoteListFragment">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listHeader"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Device List"
        android:id="@+id/listHeader"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="#f4438fd3"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:text="Add"
            android:onClick="addDevice"
            android:id="@+id/addDevice"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f4438fd3"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:onClick="deleteDevice"
            android:id="@+id/deleteDevice"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f4438fd3"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_remote_list_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/deviceName" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/listElementSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ListBoxSize" android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to create a header and footer.

In the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
    TextView tv;

    static final String[] numbers = new String[]{"one", "two", "three",
        "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven",
        "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen",
        "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty", "twenty one",
        "twenty two"};
    View header;
    ViewGroup footer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_id);

        //code to add header and footer to listview
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header,        listView,
            false);
        ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, listView,
            false);
        listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
        listView.addFooterView(footer, null, false);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

In the activity xml.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</ListView>
```

Create two xml files in the resources/ layout

header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="HEADER"
        android:background="#cf9f99" />

</LinearLayout>
```

footer.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="FOOTER"
        android:background="#cf9f99" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image][image]

Comment: hi @Ms Yvette thanks for a quick response just want to check will this not make the header and footer stick to the list and not float on scrolling

Comment: yes so that is what is not needed :) . I needed header and footer to be fixed to screen that is it should stay fixed on screen (float) when list is scrolled